# Is there a PowerShell "string does not contain" cmdlet or syntax?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I'm reading in a text file. I'm then doing a Foreach-Object over the text file and am only interested in the lines that do NOT contain strings that are in `$arrayOfStringsNotInterestedIn`.

What is the syntax for this?

```
   Get-Content $filename | Foreach-Object {$_}
```

Comment: You can probably use *-notmatch* or *-notlike* in conjunction with each of the strings in your array.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If $arrayofStringsNotInterestedIn is an [array] you should use -notcontains:

```
Get-Content $FileName | foreach-object { `
   if ($arrayofStringsNotInterestedIn -notcontains $_) { $) }
```

or better (IMO)

```
Get-Content $FileName | where { $arrayofStringsNotInterestedIn -notcontains $_}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the -notmatch operator to get the lines that don't have the characters you are interested in.

```
     Get-Content $FileName | foreach-object { 
     if ($_ -notmatch $arrayofStringsNotInterestedIn) { $) }
```

Comment: Has anyone even tried this?  When I try it the syntax is incorrect and it returns every line in the file.

Comment: -notmatch now. Thanks, works better than -notcontains for string in a string

Comment: thanks for pointing me to an operator I hadn't explored. this worked well.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude the lines that contain any of the strings in $arrayOfStringsNotInterestedIn, you should use:

```
(Get-Content $FileName) -notmatch [String]::Join('|',$arrayofStringsNotInterestedIn)
```

The code proposed by Chris only works if $arrayofStringsNotInterestedIn contains the full lines you want to exclude.